# Fastlane - update 2 screen shot out of 5 existing screenshots

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

Let's say I have 5 screenshots already uploaded to iTunes Connect. Now for the current update, I need to update only two screenshots, 3rd & 4th only. My `Fastlane` screenshot folder has the two updated screenshot with name screen3, screen4, now if I do `Fastlane` deliver it replaces the first two screenshot, not that two that I want to change...

Can anything be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

`deliver` currently does not support replacing single screenshots at a specific index. You could do it with `spaceship` the library behind `fastlane`. There you can specify the screenshot order and only replace the `n` screenshot.